# Dagger2 do not generate Dagger* classes

Tags: android, dagger-2

Dagger2 does not create classes Dagger*. I created the interface IDaggerTestModule, but the class DaggerIDaggerTestModule not created! All libraries have. Maybe "apt" is not triggered???

my test project: https://github.com/gc986/Dagger2Test

MyConfig:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta2'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.netelement.gc986.mpos_android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    /*compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }*/

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'

    // Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'

    // Dagger
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    // Butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.3.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.3.0'

}
```

User.java

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

DaggerUser.java

```
@Module
public class DaggerUser {

    @Provides
    public User provideUser(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("name1");
        user.setLastName("name2");

        return user;
    }

}
```

IDaggerFactory.java

```
@Singleton
@Component (
        modules = {DaggerUser.class}
)
public interface IDaggerFactory {

    void inject();
    User user();

}
```

This not create...

public class DaggerApplication extends Application {

```
IDaggerFactory component;

public static IDaggerFactory component(Context context){
    return ((DaggerApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).component;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    component = -->DaggerIDaggerFactory<--
                .builder()
                .daggerUser(new DaggerUser())
                .build();
}
```

}

Comment: Remember: Dagger generates code for `@Component` interfaces, not `@Module` classes. If your IDaggerTestModule is actually a `@Component`, please clarify your question and consider changing its name. (It may also help to see your IDaggerTestModule interface.)

Comment: For those developers who are not able to resolve this problem yet, please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947043/dagger2-is-not-generating-dagger-classes/46537576#46537576. Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because this method in your component interface  doesn't actually do anything. Remove it.

```
void inject();
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, just got home from vacation. So first thing, removing `void inject()` fixes the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a valid component method: inject()

After that, it says "Cannot find symbol" in `DaggerApplication` because it hasn't been imported yet, so I added the import

> import com.gc986.dagger2test.di.DaggerIDaggerFactory;

And then it compiled successfully

**So in reality, you forgot to import the newly generated `DaggerIDaggerFactory` class in your Java file**

Comment: Sorry friend, but this has not solved the problem. I removed the "void inject();", but "DaggerIDaggerFactory" is not created.
I work in Linux, maybe this is the effect?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! But there is something strange. I've commented out the body of the class "DaggerApplication", then did a "Clean Project", then "Rebuild Project". Only then can the class DaggerIDaggerFactory" was created by the system. I checked it 2 times (creating new projects). The mystic!

Comment: Yeah you have to call `rebuild project ` to generate the new components